# How to seed EF Core 2.1 data without that data always in memory

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.8.4

.NET Core 2.1

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.3

According to the guidance I've read, [data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) is the method I should use to generate a migration that inserts data. [EntityTypeBuilder.HasData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.hasdata?view=efcore-2.1) is the method to use to ensure the migration contains the code to insert the data, and [DbContext.OnModelCreating](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding) is the time to do it.

I have a large table I'm populating from a file in DbContext.OnModelCreating. I also have an NUnit test project which contains an integration test that executes code that touches the database. That test is currently failing, because instantiating my derived DbContext results in a call to OnModelCreating, which tries to open my large file and import it. Since my test project is creating my execution context, the relative path to my data file is different, so it can't find the file and it throws an exception.

That's not the problem. I can easily look for the file and return if it doesn't exist. But this exception draws my attention to the fact that [OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx) is always going to be called the first time I instantiate my derived DbContext class in an app domain, which means this entire table is going to exist in memory even though I haven't queried the database for its contents, which seems to defeat the purpose of having a database.

So, I can remove the the code in OnModelCreating that reads this file (and suddenly my tests pass), but if I do that, the next time I add a migration, the code in the Migration.Up will wipe out the contents of that table. Unless I erase the EntityTypeBuilder.HasData call for this table generated in the ModelSnapshot, which seems like a really dirty hack, and which I'll have to manually undo before performing a similar series of dirty hacks in the future any time I want to change the contents of this table.

So, the question is, how do I provide seed data for migrations without having that data automatically loaded into memory when I instantiate my DbContext and without manually editing the ModelSnapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to reset your `DbContext` to its initial state (w/o any tracked entities) after seed data is saved.  If so, detach all entities tracked by the `DbContext`:

```
foreach( var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries() )
{
    entry.State = EntityState.Detatched;
}
```

Edit:

To address the comment, seed data is only required for migrations.  If you can use a different `DbContext` for your migrations, derive another `DbContext` from your current `DbContext` for use with your migrations and only include the seed data in that `DbContext`.

Comment: But there should be no need to save and detach the data every time I instantiate my DbContext, should there?

Comment: @user1738511 - the seed data is only required for migrations.  I'd suggest deriving a `DbContext` from your current `DbContext` specifically for use with your migrations

Comment: That's elegant. Thanks.